# What will be a natural way to describe something someone has already sipped or eaten

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If some **takes a sip** of a juice or any other liquid and another person drinks that from the same glass, what will be a natural word in English for that?

And of **someone eats** something that a person has already **taken a bite of,** what will be a natural way to express this?

I read a word **"Ort"**. But it was archaic and old and was used for "food leftovers" and **not describing something that is not a leftover bit something another person has already eaten a bit and might eat later on**.

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to write "already **spiked** or eaten" in the title? It does not really fit, according to my understanding.

Comment: Related question: [How to refuse an offer of partially eaten food?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/30918/9161)

Comment: I guess there's no alternative in English...

Answer (score 1):

There is no word in English for this. The specific cultural taboo of "eating from a plate that another person has already eaten from" doesn't exist in English speaking cultures. Indeed it is common at a restaurant to offer "a taste" of your food to others at the table.

So we can say "Have a taste of my wine", "Have a sip of my coke" or "Have a bit of my curry", or "Have a bite of my pizza". But it would still be "my pizza" whether I or you have eaten any of it.

"Ort" is not a word used in modern English. "Leftovers" is food that we don't intend to eat now (but may keep to use up later). Leftovers may have been plated or unplated (still in the cooking pot).

Comment: Huh, the data bears your statement out, but "orts" is pretty common in my neck of the woods, as a close synonym for "crumbs" or food remainders that are slightly larger than crumbs.

Comment: if leftover is the food to be used later then how to describe the food which someone leaves in the plate when one is full?

Comment: That is called waste.

Comment: That waste can also be called *scraps* or *table scraps*. You can feed your dog scraps from the table. You wouldn't feed it leftovers, unless of course you were out of dog food and felt that the dog's need was greater than your own.

Answer (score 0):

James K is correct that there isn't a particular taboo against this, so there isn't really a specific word. But to answer your question as posed, the natural word is **sharing**. In polite society this usually implies that the original eater offered a taste, a sip, a bite.

If the original eater isn't aware that a sip or bite is being taken, you would often say that the other person is **stealing** a bite.

In the specific case where the food being stolen is comprised of individual morsels, such as french fries, peas, or chocolate candies, one could say that they were being **filched**

> **filch** | filCH | *v.* informal
>   pilfer or steal (something, especially a thing of small value) in a casual way